# AEM: Retrieve properties of all node of container node using query builder

Tags: aem, query-builder, predicate

I am newbie in Adobe Experience Manager. I am working on [Query Builder](https://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/aem-query-builder/#:%7E:text=Troubleshooting%20AEM%20Query-,What%20is%20Query%20Builder%3F,predicates%20in%20key%20value%20form.). Here down is my query which is tried by me to search all node properties of `container_copy` node.

```
path=/content/pojoName/au/en/enquiry-form
type=cq:PageContent
1_property=jcr:content/root/container/container/container_copy
1_property.operation=exists

2_property=jcr:content/root/container/container/container_copy
2_property.value=singleText
```

Here down is the snapshot of my page in CRXDE

[image]

Comment: May you please specify - do you need to get all properties of container_copy node or properties of children nodes?

Comment: @dzenisiy I need properties of children nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to search for `type=cq:PageContent`. You can search for a `sling:resourceType` property for a targeted node. Since every component in CRX will have this property

If you need to find necessary nodes only under `/content/pojoName/au/en/enquiry-form` use direct path. More global pass may be used to find components in more global area like `/content/pojoName/au/en/`

Just use the `sling:resourceType` of `container_copy` component.

```
path=/content/pojoName/au/en/enquiry-form
1_property=sling:resourceType
1_property.value=PUT_VALUE_HERE
```

If you need properties of child nodes, just iterate through the child element and get properties.

```
 Map map = new HashMap();
 map.put("path", "/content");
 map.put("1_property", "sling:resourceType");
 map.put("1_property.value", "/resource/type/of/node");
 Query query = builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(map), session);
 SearchResult result = query.getResult();

 //get properties of container_copy
 Optional.ofNullable(result.getResources)
    .forEach(r -> r.getValueMap())
 ......

 //get properties of container_copy children
 Optional.ofNullable(result.getResources)
    .forEach(r -> r.getChildren())
    .forEach(r -> r.getValueMap())
 ......
```